# Java CRC32 does not match MySQL CRC32

Tags: java, mysql

I need Java's CRC32 to match MySQL's CRC32, but I'm getting different results.

MySQL

```
MariaDB> SELECT CRC32(148595460);
+------------------+
| CRC32(148595460) |
+------------------+
|       4137475682 |
+------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Java

```
Checksum checksum = new CRC32();
checksum.update(ByteBuffer.allocate(4).putInt(148595460).array(), 0, 4);
System.out.println("Checksum: " + checksum.getValue());
```

Result: `Checksum: 747753823`

Why does this happen? I'm guessing MySQL interprets the number as a string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your observations can be explained by a close look at the APIs for MariaDB and Java:

**MariaDB:**

> Computes a cyclic redundancy check value and returns a 32-bit unsigned value. The result is NULL if the argument is NULL. **The argument is expected to be a string and (if possible) is treated as one if it is not.**

In other words, when you call `CRC32(148595460)` in MariaDB it is using the string `148595460`.  Now let's look at Java.

**Java:**

From the documentation for [`CRC32.update`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/zip/CRC32.html#update(byte[])):

> Updates the CRC-32 checksum with the specified array of bytes.

In other words, you passed in the `int` value 148595460 which then was converted to a byte array.

If you try the following Java code I believe you will get the behavior you want:

```
Checksum checksum = new CRC32();
byte[] b = "148595460".getBytes();
checksum.update(b);
system.out.println("Checksum: " + checksum.getValue());
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is just as I assumed, MySQL interprets the number as a string of characters. Passing a string of numbers to Java solves the problem:

```
Checksum checksum = new CRC32();
String id = "148595460";
checksum.update(id.getBytes(), 0, id.length());
System.out.println("Checksum: " + checksum.getValue());
```

The result: `Checksum: 4137475682`